# Strange behavior when setting null value in bound ComboBoxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I prepared a small project demonstrating my issue. It consists of two data tables with a parent-child relation. I use vb.net 2010 with framework 4.0.
- Start a new WinForm project.
- On Form1 designer, drag one BindingNavigator, one Button and two ComboBoxes.
- In code behind, copy code below:

```
Public Class Form1
 Private dsMain As DataSet
 Private WithEvents bndSource As New BindingSource

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  dsMain = New DataSet

  'Create tables
  Dim dtContacts As New DataTable("Contacts")
  Dim col As DataColumn = dtContacts.Columns.Add("IDContact", GetType(Integer))
  col.AllowDBNull = False
  col.AutoIncrement = True
  col.Unique = True
  dtContacts.Columns.Add("FullName")
  col = dtContacts.Columns.Add("IDCountry", GetType(Integer))
  col.AllowDBNull = True
  dsMain.Tables.Add(dtContacts)

  Dim dtCountries As New DataTable("Countries")
  col = dtCountries.Columns.Add("IDCountry", GetType(Integer))
  col.AllowDBNull = False
  col.AutoIncrement = True
  col.Unique = True
  dtCountries.Columns.Add("A2ISO")
  dtCountries.Columns.Add("CountryName")
  dsMain.Tables.Add(dtCountries)

  'Add relation
  Dim rel As New DataRelation("rel", dtCountries.Columns("IDCountry"), dtContacts.Columns("IDCountry"))
  dsMain.Relations.Add(rel)

  'Populate parent table
  dtCountries.Rows.Add(1, "AF", "Afghanistan")
  dtCountries.Rows.Add(2, "AL", "Albania")
  dtCountries.Rows.Add(3, "DZ", "Algeria")

  'Populate child table
  dtContacts.Rows.Add(1, "First Contact", 3)
  dtContacts.Rows.Add(2, "Second Contact", 1)

  'Set bindings
  bndSource.DataSource = dtContacts.DefaultView
  BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bndSource

  ComboBox1.DataSource = dtCountries
  ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "A2ISO"
  ComboBox1.ValueMember = "IDCountry"
  ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bndSource, "IDCountry")
  ComboBox2.DataSource = dtCountries
  ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "CountryName"
  ComboBox2.ValueMember = "IDCountry"
  ComboBox2.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bndSource, "IDCountry")

  dsMain.AcceptChanges()
 End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  ComboBox1.Text = Nothing 'Set IDCountry to DBNull, same as ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
  ComboBox2.Text = Nothing
 End Sub
End Class
```

- Run the project.
- Try to navigate back and forth, and change items in the ComboBoxes: all is correct.
- Now set IDCountry = Null in Contacts table, as it is allowed. To achieve this, click on Button1.
- In ComboBox1, if you select the same item as it was before clicking the button, you see the behavior is not correct anymore: ComboBox2 doesn't update accordingly with ComboBox1 but remains empty.
- If you select another item, from now on all is correct again.
Is this a bug in .net data binding? If so, is there any workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround I found. I didn't find the reason of the behavior I observed, but this code works for me:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged  
 If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < ComboBox2.Items.Count Then ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex  
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
 If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex < ComboBox1.Items.Count Then ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox2.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

It simply makes ComboBox selected indexes equal.
Thank you anyway.